# How do I use $SECONDS inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to save the result of the `$SECONDS` command into a variable, to print time in format `HH:MM:SS`.

This is what I've tried so far. I tried to print it in different ways and was always getting the result as `0`:

```
time_spent="$SECONDS"
echo "Time: $time_spent"
```

I want to print time spent in the shell when I close my console. I created a script that runs every time the console was closed.

Comment: How did you configure your script to run after the console is ended? Do you mean `gnome-terminal` or Alt+F1 console? There might be other options available...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get `$SECONDS` into HH:MM:SS format you will need to do some (integer) math:

```
secs=$SECONDS
hrs=$(( secs/3600 )); mins=$(( (secs-hrs*3600)/60 )); secs=$(( secs-hrs*3600-mins*60 ))

printf 'Time spent: %02d:%02d:%02d\n' $hrs $mins $secs
Time spent: 431:48:03
```

Comment: I think it would be better to save `$SECONDS` as a variable first -- to keep consistency (not sure how much of fraction of a second would be left for doing the last two calculations).

Comment: @steeldriver do you know if there is a milliseconds version of the same solution ? thx

Comment: @heemayl good point, done - sorry I only just noticed your comment as the result of the recent one

Comment: @BuriB no I don't - sorry

Answer (score 10):

If you're sure that `$SECONDS` will be less than 1 day (i.e. 86400 seconds), then [GNU core-utils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html) `date` does a pretty good job of the required formatting:

```
$ date -ud "@$SECONDS" "+Time elapsed: %H:%M:%S"
Time elapsed: 00:32:05
$
```

Answer (score 7):

You've referenced the `bash` internal variable `SECONDS` (which outputs the number of seconds elapsed since the current instance of shell is invoked) and saved the value as another variable `time_spent`. Now, after that every time you check the value of variable `time_spent`, you would get the same value -- the saved one, at the time of expansion of `SECONDS`.

To dynamically get `SECONDS`, you should reference `$SECONDS` directly rather than using an intermediate variable:

```
echo "Time: $SECONDS"
```

If you insist on using an intermediate variable, make sure to do the expansion of `$SECONDS` every time.

---

Regarding the value of `SECONDS` being `0`, you can easily reproduce this:

```
% bash -c 'echo $SECONDS'
0
```

The point is: when you're calculating the value, it's not a second yet, so the value is being `0`, correctly.

Comment: this is the whole script, i think it's because i execute a shell script and at this moment the SECONDS variable value is 0. WHat might be a solution for this kind of work. I' need the time spend in shell output when i close my console, so i created shell script which run everytime i close console

Comment: @Andrew Check my edits.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick one that gives hours minutes and seconds since the shell has been opened:

```
~$ cat how_long_open 
#!/bin/bash

time=$SECONDS
printf '%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($time/3600)) $(($time%3600/60)) $(($time%60))
```

Since scripts run in a subshell, the best way to get output is to source the script instead of calling it.

Examples:

*Without sourcing the script*

```
~$ ./how_long_open 
0h:0m:0s
```

*With sourcing the script*

```
~$ source ./how_long_open 
1h:24m:40s
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use `printf`:

```
SECONDS=0
# do something
TZ=UTC printf '%(%H:%M:%S)T\n' $SECONDS
```